# Where is 'source text' determined, using Poedit

Tags: wordpress, gettext, poedit

I'm fairly new to Poedit, but I'm trying to make a translation of a Wordpress theme. I think I'm slowly beginning to understand the whole I18n, l10n and po, pot and mo thing.

I've purchased a Poedit license and are then trying to create a new pot-file. When I choose the folder that I'm trying to translate, then it automatically sets the language that I'm trying to translate from to be English (and I haven't chosen it). It's an old theme, that I've modified and used, so some of the words on this image is english, but the theme is actually in danish.

So where do I change the language that Poedit thinks that I'm translating from?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gettext translation system assumes that the source text is always in English. There are good reasons for it, including the fact that it is the lingua franca of computing and that designing plural forms handling for any source languages would be insane. The absolutely best thing you can do is to develop your code in English.

Consequently, the PO file format (which isn't Poedit's, but a standard thing) has no way to encode the source language — there's no need, it is known to be English.

Some developers insist on using non-English source texts anyway, against their better judgement (this is relatively common in Germany for some reason). To accommodate this, Poedit autodetects the language since 1.8 using CLD2 (i.e. the same thing Chrome uses). There's no way to override this, because... well, see above.

In other words, in your case, Poedit sees the source as English because it *is* primarily English. If it were in Danish, Poedit would detect that. Case in point: *your entire screenshot (save for maybe 1 word) is in English* and not Danish as you say the file is.

There are no negative consequences to misdetected source language, except for suboptimal suggestions. Don't worry about it.

Comment: This is so stupid however, as there are easily millions of programs developed with strings in other languages, and when you want to translate one of them this awkward situation occurs... But if it only impacts the suggestions, then I'll bear with the warning when I translate from "English" to English.

Comment: "Millions of programs" may be overestimating it just a little bit… gettext's design is quite reasonable choice, certainly not "stupid" if you consider where, when and for what it was created. And in any case, as I explained above, Poedit *does* support other languages and does detect them very well. You only get "English to English" warning when you actually do have (majority of) the source text in English. Don't dismiss it as "stupid", check your file instead.

Comment: The majority of programs developed for only one local or national company have no internationalisation built-in at all, which means that all the IHM strings will be in the local language only. Most often internationalisation (and localisation) is added only as an after thought when the product or the company has the opportunity to expand to foreign markets. This said, I have no problems with poedit defaulting to English, just that I would prefer to be able to change it (especially since it tries to guess the language, why not enabling the possibility to edit the source language in the PO?).

Comment: As for my specific problem, I agree it's a mess because I've got strings both in English and in French. As so many English words look like French ones, I am not surprised that overall it would guess that English is the source language, but officially on this project the source language is supposed to be French and the English words are due to very sloppy project management. So yes, I could say my project design is even more "stupid", but that's life ^^ I +1ed anyway as this answers this and my question.

Comment: "Why not enabling the possibility to edit the source language in the PO"? Because, as I explained in the above answer, there's no way to do that in the PO format...

Answer (score 9):

Since this question was answered it became possible to tell Poedit the source language using a custom header field in the PO Header. (Since 1.8.10)

```
X-Source-Language: de
```

See: [Specify the source language of the PO file](https://github.com/vslavik/poedit/wiki/PO-Extensions#additional-metadata)

Comment: Yep. Notice that it is a non-standard extension solely for Poedit's use, and only does something useful if you have mixed-language sources (otherwise detection works), so you're effectively giving Poedit *knowingly wrong* information by using it. Useful if you're doing multiple passes *and* pre-translation, or for round-tripping from XLIFF where a more fine-tuned source language that could be detected may be present (e.g. en_GB vs en), otherwise not much.

Comment: Perfect answer to change default audetect language. Add `"X-Source-Language: en\n"` in .po file. Replace `en` with the language code you need.